# Trying to get Sonar CXX Plugin working

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Setup Jenkins (with sonar plugin) and sonar (with cxx-plugin).  There is a build step to create the "......./gcovr-reports/gcovr-result-test.xml" file. Problem is coverage results to not show up ob Snar dashboard.  But it appears that sonar.runner is excuting .... but transcript does not show that CxxGcovrSensor is being run.

Answer (score 0):

what errormessages do you get?
try importing your project using maven for more details on errormessges.

I had similar issues because my pom.xml was broken. below is a working one.
be sure your folder structure looks like this:

(you need to cd to base)

base=/some/folder/myProject/    <-- put pom.xml here

src_folder=/some/folder/myProject/src

reports_folder=/some/folder/myProject/reports   (with all the subdirs for reports)

also be sure your reports are named lik: xunit-result-.xml

cd to /some/folder/myProject  and  mvn sonar:sonar
 (mvn -X sonar:sonar for debug mode)

(btw. if you get strange errors try removing all irrelevant plugins from sonar/external/plugins (just leave cxx there)

do not forget to set JAVA_PATH for sonar
goto basefolder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>NETICOA</groupId>
  <artifactId>MYPROJECT</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.10-myversion</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>myProject</name>

  <description>php svn code</description>

  <!-- pom.xml extract -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirs>
            <sourceDir>${basedir}/src</sourceDir>
          </sourceDirs>
          <!-- All of the sub configuration nodes following are needed by sonar-cxx plugin -->
          <!-- This sample provided values are default values. -->
          <!-- So you can simple remove all of it if you provide reports in the right places -->
          <xunit>
            <directory>${basedir}/reports/xunit-reports</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/xunit-result-*.xml</include>
            </includes>
          </xunit>
          <gcovr>
            <directory>${basedir}/reports/gcovr-reports</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/gcovr-reports-*.xml</include>
            </includes>
          </gcovr>
          <cppcheck>
            <directory>${basedir}/reports/cppcheck-reports</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/cppcheck-result-*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <reportsIncludeSourcePath>
              <include>..</include>
            </reportsIncludeSourcePath>
          </cppcheck>
          <cppncss>
            <directory>${basedir}/reports/cppncss-reports</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/cppncss-result-*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <reportsIncludeSourcePath>
              <include>..</include>
            </reportsIncludeSourcePath>
          </cppncss>
          <veraxx>
            <directory>${basedir}/reports/vera++-reports</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/vera++-result-*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <reportsIncludeSourcePath>
              <include>..</include>
            </reportsIncludeSourcePath>
          </veraxx>
          <valgrind>
            <directory>${basedir}/reports/valgrind-reports</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/valgrind-result-*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <reportsIncludeSourcePath>
              <include>..</include>
            </reportsIncludeSourcePath>
          </valgrind>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>  
    <!-- We have our own <configuration><sourceDirs> node inside cxx plugin configuration -->
    <!-- <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/sources</sourceDirectory> -->
  </build>
  <properties>
    <sonar.language>c++</sonar.language>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
  </properties>
</project>
```